# Windows logs and Internet activity

Tags: windows, logging

If I upload / download any file to/from Gmail is it traceable using Windows logs? What information is exactly stored in Windows logs regarding net browsing?

Comment: Have you looked at your logs?

Comment: You might get much better answers if you describe what you actually *want*.

Your question is very narrow because it assumes the PC is the only thing being looked at. Why would you? That's probably why the question got downvoted.

Say your goal is to see who leaked an important company document.
Then we might suggest looking at the firewall / network logs in the company instead of the PC.
The other way around, we will suggest very different things.

So yeah, please clarify your intentions.

Answer (score 2):

Windows is an OS and its logs concern the OS-level of activity.

Browsing the Internet is an application-level activity, not an OS activity, so there will not be OS logs on this activity.

If you want to know what *can* be logged, you could simply look at the lists of Windows event IDs.